# Gulp TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs

I want to run build command but got the error message:

**TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined.**

Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks.

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    browserify("./src/components/source.js")
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app.js')));
});
```

Below is the tracestack details:

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
    at Object.posix.resolve (path.js:426:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.saveFile [as _transform] (/Users/yzzhou/Documents/ReleasePlanner/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/index.js:36:26)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Users/yzzhou/Documents/ReleasePlanner/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Users/yzzhou/Documents/ReleasePlanner/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/Users/yzzhou/Documents/ReleasePlanner/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Users/yzzhou/Documents/ReleasePlanner/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Users/yzzhou/Documents/ReleasePlanner/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean install to ensure your deps are fully updated?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thank you for the reply. The dependent modules are all latest.

Comment: I had this issue recently as well, I was able to resolve it by downgrading from Node 6 to Node 4.4.4

Comment: I am having this issue currently, regardless of the version of node I'm using

Comment: Is any update on above I am also having the same issue. I found that in issue in Linux. please help me into this.

Comment: Which version of node you are using?
In 6.x.x this error apears.
You cna fix it by updating babel packages to lates.
Say if this helps