# gulp Iconify task throws error TypeError: Path must be a string. Received false

Tags: javascript, svg, gulp, icons

I am working on a project, not written by me, where gulp file does iconify task. Where I put svg files in images and the task converts those svg files to scss/sass. now when I run that task it has been giving me this TypeError for sometime and is really troubling and sometimes taking a lot of time.

Here is the code for iconify in gulpfile.js

```
var iconparams = {
src: './public/styles/images/icons/*.svg',
pngOutput: false,
scssOutput: './public/styles/sass',
scssSvgName: '_icons.scss', 
cssOutput: false,   
styleTemplate: './public/styles/icons.scss.mustache'    
}
gulp.task('iconify',function() {
   iconify(iconparams);
});
```

When I run `gulp iconify`, I get this output and error:

```
[18:31:08] Starting 'iconify-clean'...
[18:31:08] Finished 'iconify' after 7.55 ms
[18:31:08] Finished 'iconify-clean' after 41 ms
[18:31:08] Starting 'iconify-convert'...
[18:31:20] Finished 'iconify-convert' after 12 s
[18:31:20] Starting 'iconify-fallback'...
path.js:8
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' +
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received false
    at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
    at Object.posix.relative (path.js:495:3)
    at Stream.bufferContents         (/home/savitoj/Work/mercureup/node_modules/gulp-iconify/lib/iconify.js:108:41)
    at Stream.stream.write  (/home/savitoj/Work/mercureup/node_modules/through/index.js:26:11)
    at write (/home/savitoj/Work/mercureup/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (/home/savitoj/Work/mercureup/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/home/savitoj/Work/mercureup/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at emitReadable_ (/home/savitoj/Work/mercureup/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
    at emitReadable (/home/savitoj/Work/mercureup/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
```

I have checked on other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948998/gulp-usemin-typeerror-path-must-be-a-string-received-undefined) on Stackoverflow regarding this typeError, but no solutions for exact this issue. I see that the outputs in my `./public/styles/sass` are created but gives out error before outputting `_icons.scss`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried both node versions 5.6.0 and 4.4.4 with same error like someone suggested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176273/gulp-typeerror-path-must-be-a-string-received-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes so I figured the solution in after carefully reading the error, but as I said I received this code from someone else. As it says `TypeError: Path must be a string. Received false`.

I changed the line to

```
cssOutput: './public/styles/css',
```

and it solved the issue. I was very stressed because this was bugging me for quite sometime and I was not able to figure it out.